# Find attribute in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a bit of a Ruby on Rails newbie, I am trying to find the last record for a specific column in the database. This system accepts Bitcoins and generates and saves a Bitcoin address and later an amount is also saved.

I created the following migration:

```
  def change
   create_table :payments do |t|
    t.string :bitcoin
    t.string :amount

    t.timestamps
   end
  end
```

in the controller I have:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

   def new_address
      @balance = BlockIo.get_new_address
   end
end
```

I want to get the last saved Bitcoin address. I have tried:

```
payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
last_payment = payment.bitcoin.last
```

I also tried:

```
payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
last_payment = payment.pluck(:bitcoin).last
```

And a few other combinations as I checked through Active Record documentation. Please assist me with the correct syntax to get the last saved bitcoin address.

In the show view, you can access the data via:

Please advise how to check last saved bitcoin address based on the above information. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply

```
last_payment = Payment.last.bitcoin
```

Answer (score 1):

Having

```
payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
```

The way to get it's `bitcoin` attribute is to do:

```
payment.bitcoin
```

Since each payment has only one `bitcoin` there is no way to find the last one - there is always only one for a specific payment object.

If you want to get the last (which is newest) payment's bitcoin:

```
Payment.last.bitcoin
```